# Assets Image Rotation

Tags: assets, control-panel, file-uploads

We have a client that uses a Windows computer that auto rotates images from his camera, but when uploaded are rotated 90 degrees. We know you can rotate images in the File Manager, but it's not very user friendly and we usually try to keep clients out of there, hence Assets. Does anyone know a solution or plugin we could implement into Assets or Control Panel in general that's easier to use?

EE v2.5.5
Assets v2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at CE Image? It can do on the fly rotating of images:

- http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters#rotate

Comment: This may not account for varying rotations (hold your phone 90 degrees and snap photo (A), then flip it 180 degrees and snap photo (B), these photos would need different rotations).

Comment: The original question was regarding the Control Panel & Assets (interface) add-on for a permanent rotation solution, rather than on-the-fly frontend. But any solution would need control over the amount of degrees moved and in which direction. Channel Images allows it (http://www.devdemon.com/blog/crop_rotate_flip_in_channel_images_expressionengine_images_made_easy), but that's not quite the same as Assets. Doubtful that Assets would be extended to have that functionality and looking at the docs, there's no relevant hook that can be used.